# Font Awesome no longer working on browser Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, font-awesome

I've had Font Awesome on my extension (Chrome & Firefox) for almost a year but now the icons no longer work:

Manifest:

```
...
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://kit.fontawesome.com/{id}.js; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Include:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/{id}.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

An error in the console:

```
{id}.js:2 Font Awesome Kit: TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about the answer I have discovered the solution. I logged into my Fontawesome account and grabbed the CDN version of the CSS link. This now works with no issue.

I also added it to my manifest.json in the `content_security_policy` area.